# Change element in list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and one of the elements in each list is an empty list that I need to convert to None. Example:

```
lst: [[0, [], 1], [1, [], 2], [2, [], 3]]

Desired Output: [[0, None, 1], [1, None, 2], [2, None, 3]]
```

I tried [None for y[1] in y for f in lst] but doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test whether the element in question is an empty list so you know whether or not to replace it:

```
>>> lst = [[0, [], 1], [1, [], 2], [2, [], 3]]
>>> [[y if y != [] else None for y in x] for x in lst]
[[0, None, 1], [1, None, 2], [2, None, 3]]
```

If you know that each sublist is three elements and that you will always want to replace the middle item, you can also just do it positionally, e.g. by destructuring:

```
>>> [[i, None, k] for [i, j, k] in lst]
[[0, None, 1], [1, None, 2], [2, None, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

using a for loop enables us to do the modifications inplace:

```
lst = [[0, [], 1], [1, [], 2], [2, [], 3]]

for ind_outer, sub in enumerate(lst):
    for ind_inner, item in enumerate(sub):
        if item == []:
            lst[ind_outer][ind_inner] = None
print(lst)
```

result: `[[0, None, 1], [1, None, 2], [2, None, 3]]`